# Can i wait for a process termination that is not a child of current shell terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, process, kill

I have a script that has to kill a certain number of times a resource managed by a high avialability middelware. It basically checks whether the resource is running and kills it afterwards, i need the timestamp of when the proc is really killed. So i have done this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date +"%T,%N") :New measures Run" > /home/hassan/logs/measures.log
for i in {1..50}

do
    echo "Iteration: $i"
    PID=`ps -ef | grep  "/home/hassan/Desktop/pcmAppBin pacemaker_app/MainController"|grep -v "grep" | awk {'print$2'}`
    if [ -n "$PID" ]; then
        echo "$(date +"%T,%N") :Killing $PID" >> /home/hassan/logs/measures.log
        ps -ef | grep  "/home/hassan/Desktop/pcmAppBin pacemaker_app/MainController"|grep -v "grep" | awk {'print "kill -9 " $2'} | sh
        wait $PID
    else
        PID=`ps -ef | grep  "/home/hassan/Desktop/pcmAppBin pacemaker_app/MainController"|grep -v "grep" | awk {'print$2'}`
        until [ -n "$PID" ]; do
                sleep 2
        PID=`ps -ef | grep  "/home/hassan/Desktop/pcmAppBin pacemaker_app/MainController"|grep -v "grep" | awk {'print$2'}`
        done
    fi

done
```

But with my wait command i get the following error message: wait: pid xxxx is not a child of this shell

Answer (score 1):

I assume that You started the child processes from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and then start this script to wait for. The problem is that the child processes are not the children of the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) running the script, but the children of its parent!

If You want to launch a script inside the the current [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) You should start with `.`.

An example. You start a `vim` and then You make is stop pressing `^Z` (later you can use `fg` to get back to `vim`). Then You can get the list of jobs by using the˙`jobs` command.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 vim myfile
```

Then You can create a script called `test.sh` containing just one command, called `jobs`. Add execute right (e.g. `chmod 700 test.sh`), then start it:

```
$ cat test.sh 
jobs
~/dev/fi [3:1]$ ./test.sh
~/dev/fi [3:1]$ . ./test.sh 
[1]+  Stopped                 vim myfile
```

As the first version creates a new [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) session no jobs are listed. But using `.` the script runs in the present [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script having exactly one chold process (namely `vim`). So launch the script above using the `.` so no child [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will be created.

Be aware that defining any variables or changing directory (and a lot more) will affect to your environment! E.g. PID will be visible by the calling [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)!

**Comments:**

- Do not use `...|grep ...|grep -v ... |awk ---` pipe snakes! Use `...|awk...` instead!
- In most Linux-es you can use something like this `ps -o pid= -C pcmAppBin` to get just the pid, so the complete pipe can be avoided.
- To call an external program from [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you could try `system("mycmd");` built-in

I hope this helps a bit!