# Why does wait generate “<pid> is not a child of this shell” error if a pipe is used afterwards?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subprocess, pipe

In the following I create a background process and wait for it to complete.

```
$ bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  &  wait $!
[1] 46950
[1]+  Exit 1                  bash -c "sleep 5 | false"
$ echo $?
1
```

This works and the prompt returns after 5 seconds.

However, `wait` returns an error if I use one more pipe after it.

```
$ bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  &  wait $!  | true
[1] 49493
-bash: wait: pid 49493 is not a child of this shell
hbaba@mbp-005063:~/misc$ echo $?
0
hbaba@mbp-005063:~/misc$ ps -T -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
980771313 49493 69771   0 12:56AM ttys056    0:00.00 bash -c sleep 5 | false
980771313 49498 49493   0 12:56AM ttys056    0:00.00 sleep 5
    0 49555 69771   0 12:56AM ttys056    0:00.01 ps -T -f
```

What is happening here?

---

I am using bash version `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`

I can reproduce the wait error every time. 
I *think* it has something to do with each pipe being a separate subshell. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127346/212862

Maybe the wait $! command looks for the child process in the wrong shell.
The error message mentions the 49493 pid. That is indeed the right pid for the `bash -c …` Command. The `ps -T` shows that.

There are relevant questions [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048628/wait-child-process-but-get-error-pid-is-not-a-child-of-this-shell) and [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951393/can-i-wait-for-a-process-termination-that-is-not-a-child-of-current-shell-termin). But in them there is no pipe usage after the `wait` built-in.

**Update**

I had a misunderstanding about operator precedence in bash between the `&` and `|`. @randomir pointed that out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753750/5771861).  Adding curly braces makes the `wait` wait on the previously backgrounded process. For example:

```
{ bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  &  wait $! ; } | true
```

This does not return the same wait error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `sleep 5 | false`?

Comment: @Cyrus. Nothing with `sleep 5 | false`. In my real example, I have a long running process that fails at the end. I want to wait on it then continue with another pipe. This `sleep 5 | false` was a representative example.

Comment: What does it show if you do ps -f to get at the parent PID?

Comment: Bash manual: *Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).*

Comment: @Nick updated my question with `ps -T -f ` output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two key points to observe here:

- `wait` (a shell built-in) can wait only (the shell's) children
- each command in a pipeline runs in a separate subshell

So, when you say:

```
cmd & wait $!
```

then `cmd` is run in your current shell, in background, and `wait` (being the shell's built-in) can wait on `cmd`'s PID, since `cmd` is a child of that shell (and therefore a child of `wait`).

On the other hand, when you say:

```
cmd & wait $! | cmd2
```

then `cmd` is still run in your current shell, *but* the pipe induces a new subshell for `wait` (a new `bash` process) in which `cmd` is *not its child*, and `wait` **can not wait on its sibling** (a child of its parent).

As an additional clarification of shell's grammar - the `&` operator (along with `;`, `&&` and `||`) separates *pipelines*, forming *lists*. So, a *list* is a sequence of *pipelines*, and a *pipeline* is a sequence of commands separated by `|`.

That means the last example above is equivalent to:

```
cmd & { wait $! | cmd2; }
```

and **not** to this:

```
{ cmd & wait $! ; } | cmd2
```

which is equivalent to what you have expected.

Comment: Are you saying that in the second example, `wait` gets executed in the same subshell as `cmd2` ?

Comment: No. In the last example, `cmd` is executed in one shell, `wait` in second, and `cmd2` in third. Let me add that clarification to my answer.

Comment: Wauvv, thanks @randomir. I had a major misunderstanding regarding operator precedence. I was thinking that `&` and `|` had the reversed precedence compared to how they actually work. Thanks for realizing that mistake .

Answer (score 0):

Bash manual:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
>   a subshell).

You can check this with:

```
$ echo "me1: $BASHPID"
me1: 34438
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 34989
$ echo "me2: $BASHPID, child: $!"
me2: 34438, child: 34989
$ true | echo "me3: $BASHPID, child: $!"
me3: 34991, child: 34989
```

The first and second `echo` (`me1` and `me2`) are executed in the context of the top shell (`34438`). The `sleep` child process (`34989`) is one of its children. The third `echo` (`me3`) is executed in the context of a subshell (`34991`). The `sleep` process is not one of its children any more.

Comment: Let's say `bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  & n="$!"` is spawned in subshell X. In subshell X, the `bash -c "sleep 5 | false"` is again spawned in the background in subshell Y. Then for the last pipe the `echo $n` is spawned in subshell Z. Does the $! variable in subshell X get modified because of the subshell Z ?

Comment: How about this command: `bash -c "sleep 5 | true"  & n=$! ;  echo "From first pipe $n"  | cat && echo "From seconds pipe $n"` It prints `[1] 54035
From first pipe 54035
From seconds pipe 54035`

Comment: If I run your command, `bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  & n="$!" | echo $n` bash tells me `$ bash -c "sleep 5 | false"  & n="$!" | echo $n
-bash: !": event not found`

Comment: Removing the quotes around $! removes that error. But then nothing is printed. Are you sure by the time you executed that command there was already no $n defined in your shell ?

Comment: Sorry, my "*proof*" was bogus. I fixed it.

Comment: What is your bash version? It behaves differently in my case. I am on mac os el capitan `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`.  First of all `echo "$!"` results in `-bash: !": event not found`. So I removed the double quotes from your examples. For me `$BASHPID` is also empty so I used `$$`:  The background job:  `$ jobs -l    [1]+  3353 Running                 sleep 10000 &`  First case:    `$  echo me:\ $$,\ child:\ $!             
      me: 69771, child: 3353` Second case `$ true | echo me:\ $$,\ child:\ $!               
       me: 69771, child: 3353`

Comment: Strangely in my case `$  echo $$  | cat;  echo $$  | cat;   echo $$` prints the same 69771  pid 3 times. I am very interested in what I am missing here.

Comment: You must be using a bash higher than 4.0 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203475/212862

Comment: I realize in my bash the `echo $$`  does not work as I expected. For example: `$ ( echo $$ && echo $PPID && sleep 10;) & true | cat` prints `[3] 7475
69771
69749` 
This is very strange. The pid of the background process is 7475 but `echo $$` in it prints 69771, which is the top level bash in that terminal

Comment: @HakanBaba I am also on Mac OS (Yosemite) but I replaced the default bash by the MacPort more recent version. I will not try to show you another proof that would work with your version of bash but the principle remains the same: commands in a pipe are executed in subshells.